# Turning an integral equation into a differential equation

Tags: integration

I have the following integral equation :
$$y(x)=1+\int\limits_0^x\frac{\mathrm dt}{(t+y(t))^2}$$
and I'm required to turn it into a differential equation with a random initial condition. I've used the fundamental theorem of calculus and ended up with :
$$y'(x)=\frac{1}{(x+y(x))^2}\qquad y(x_0)=y_0$$
Is it the correct way to present the same equation or have I done anything wrong ?
Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: also pretty sure the denominator should have $x$, not $1$

Comment: Yes. I've been confused while typing it (corrected it) ,does it now make sense to you ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the initial condition is really random. For any ODE of the form $y'(x)=f(x,y)$, we can transform it to integral form by integrating from $x_0$ to $x$:

$$\int_{x_0}^xy'(t)dt=\int_{x_0}^xf(t,y)dt\quad\Rightarrow\quad y(x)-y(x_0)=\int_{x_0}^xf(t,y)dt$$
$$\Rightarrow\quad y(x)=y(x_0)+\int_{x_0}^xf(t,y)dt$$
where $y(x_0):=y_0$ is the initial condition. In your case, it seems to me that $f(x,y)=\frac{1}{(x+y)^2}$ with initial condition $y(0)=1.$

Answer (score 0):

lets let:
$$f(t)=\frac{1}{(t+y)^2}$$
then we have:
$$y(x)=1+\int\limits_0^xf(t)\,\mathrm dt$$
differentiating both sides gives us:
$$\begin{align}y'(x)
=&f(x)-f(0)\\
=&\frac{1}{(x+y(x))^2}-\frac{1}{y^2(0)}\end{align}$$